# Try-Catch Statement Trouble

Tags: android, try-catch

So i've got this section of code in the screenshot below that are causing Type IOExceptions.

http://southwestdesign.org.uk/Code.jpg

I'm told that I need to wrap it in a try-catch block, wrapping each invididual block with a try catch eliminates the errors, but force closes on Android. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://1.php");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            textView.append(line);
        }
    }
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: you should read something basic about java. i suggest thinking in java

Comment: You should google even before anything else.

Comment: I agree, SO should be your last resort

Answer (score 4):

You seem to do Network IO on the UI thread, which is a bad idea. So since Android 2.3, the system "catches" this and kills the process.

You should put the

```
 HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

into a background thread e.g. by using an `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {

   //do something here
   //call method

}catch (IOException ioe){

// do something else
// log ioe

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be something like this:

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {

   try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://1.php");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader
    (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        textView.append(line);
    }

    }catch (IOException ex){
    }
}
```

more preferably use `AsyncTask` to get this done on a separate thread.